# Removing duplicate records using another table's oid

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, duplicates

```
Table 1          Table 2
--------         --------
oid              oid (J)
sequence         trip_id
stop             
trip_update_id (J)
```

`(J) = join`

`Table 1` and `Table 2` are updated ever 30 seconds from an api simultaneously.

At the end of each day `Table 1` has been filled with 98% duplicate data, this is because the data feed includes both new data generated in the last 30 seconds, and all data generated in previous feeds from the same day. As a result `Table 1` is filled with mostly duplicate data (the oid is automatically generated upon insertion, therefore all oid are unique).

`Table 2` has all unique records, therefore my question is what is the sql to turn `Table 1` into all unique records for each `trip_id` in `Table 2`.

Comment: There are different methods for deleting duplicate (de-duplication) records from a table, each of them has its own pros and cons.

Using correlated subquery
Using temporary table
Creating new table with distinct records and renaming it..
Using Common Table Expression (CTE)
Using Fuzzy Group Transformation in SSIS
Using MERGE Statement

Comment: I would instead enhance the insertion script that gets data from the API to make sure it check the data before insert. The insertion script would use a MERGE or other UPSERT method.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Fora table1 trip_update_id value, which row to keep? Lowest/highest oid?

Comment: So, if `oid` is unique, but has values shared (used for join) between Table_1 and Table_2, and Table_2 has no duplicates, why not just "`DELETE FROM Table_1 WHERE oid NOT IN (SELECT oid FROM Table_2)`"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand what the problem is, but here comes a few suggestions.

To remove rows from table1 with trip_update_id values not found in table2:

```
delete from table1
    where trip_update_id not in (select trip_id from table2 where trip_id is not null)
```

(The `is not null` part is very important if trip_id is allowed to have NULL values!!!)

To duplicate remove trip_update_id rows from table 1, keep the one with highest oid:

```
delete from table1
   where oid not in (select max(oid) from table1
                     group by trip_update_id)
```